# Jenkins3-X | Terraform Destroy | Error - if EKS not fully created |

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks, jenkins-x

Getting an error to destroy the EKS cluster, related issue [GitHub](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/1050#issue-721052220)

```
Error: "url" has to use HTTPS scheme (i.e. begin with https://)

  on .terraform/modules/eks-jx.cluster.eks/irsa.tf line 14, in resource "aws_iam_openid_connect_provider" "oidc_provider":
  14:   url             = flatten(concat(aws_eks_cluster.this[*].identity[*].oidc.0.issuer, [""]))[0]
```

```
terraform -v
Terraform v0.13.4
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.11.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes v1.11.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local v1.4.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v2.1.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v2.3.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0
```

and JX:
`jx version version: 3.0.633`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this I had to edit the:

`vi .terraform/modules/eks-jx.cluster.eks/irsa.tf`

and from:

```
  url             = flatten(concat(aws_eks_cluster.this[*].identity[*].oidc.0.issuer, [""]))[0]
```

change/include `https://`:

```
  url             = flatten(concat(aws_eks_cluster.this[*].identity[*].oidc.0.issuer, ["https://"]))[0]
```

after run `terraform destroy` and it should work!